# send data through ajax use value as paragraph php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm really inexperienced when it comes to PHP, and I've been trying to write my own kind of "adminpage", a really simple one. The problem is when I'm passing a value with ajax from the adminpage to the index page, the value is not appearing in the paragraph.

html adminpage.php (page which ajax request is sent from):

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <textarea class="form-control textarea"  rows="5" placeholder="Tak text 1"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary text-change1">Submit</button>
        <textarea class="form-control textarea" rows="5" placeholder="Tak text 2"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary text-change2">Submit</button>
</div>
```

index.php, page which is receiving the request

```
<?php

 $text = $_POST['text'];

?> 
<div class="desc-text">
   <p class="roof">
      <?= $text ?>
   </p>
</div>
```

Ajax:

```
 $(".text-change1").click(function(){

 if($(this).attr("class").indexOf("text-change1") != -1){
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"index.php",
    data:{ text:text },
    success:function(){
    alert("message sent!");
    }, error:function(){
      alert("Something went wrong");
    }
   });
  });
```

The goal here is to add the data sent through ajax into the mentioned paragraphs html.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
success:function(){
```

you never capture the output/return value of the the PHP script, and therefore don't insert anything into your page. You need something more like this:

```
success: function(response) {
     $('#place_to_insert_response').html(response);
}
```

Comment: I may have formulated my question wrong, what I want to do is use the string, which im sending from the first php page, in a paragraph on the destination page, index.php.

Comment: and that's exactly what the above code does. you just need to provide the appropriate DOM location for your insertion point, e.g. the `#place_to_insert_response`

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being stupid, but i really don't understand. The response I'm getting is the entire php page, including the html code, and since the paragraph is on the page which is receiveing the string, trying to set the html of the paragraph in the response doesn't work because it says that it is undefined.

       success:function(data){
            $('.roof').html(data) // Roof is undefined here 
       }

Comment: you're getting raw php code? then the php code is not being executed, and the server is misconfigured.

Comment: No, no php code, just the HTML, so the whole page is returned in the data variable, in html format.

Comment: then you need to show more code, or at least put comments showing structure where you've removed code to keep things short.

Comment: ok. what you're getting is what you're sending. **ANY** output from php becomes part of the ajax response. since you've wrapped your form field in html, you get that html as well. If you want **JUST** the form field value, then you should have `<?php echo $_POST['text']; exit;`.

Answer (score 0):

I sent the text to a textfile with ajax then I read the text file after $(document).ready to update the paragraph from the admin page.